# Vue js : Axios post getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using vue.js with axios to post my data.
Here i am calling two api's one on response of another with same data.
First api responds with 200 but on connecting second it returns with connection close 500 Internal Server Error.

//Axios

```
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('myFile', this.chart_image);
formData.append('signal_title', this.form.signal_title)

axios.post('../api/trades/add.php' , formData, )
    .then(function(response){

        axios.post('../bot.php',  
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

        )
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
    });
```

On response I am getting like this in array.

```
chart_image:File(777835)
 lastModified:1247549551674
 lastModifiedDate:Tue Jul 14 2009 11:02:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
 name:"Penguins.jpg"
 size:777835
 type:"image/jpeg"
```

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
I am using to extract the data from $update.
How to extract $update->form->chart_image->name ???
Any help would be very much helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you access the server side debugging tools?

Comment: I am getting my expected data on second connection but after that it fails to execute.

Comment: could you pls share a screen of your browser inspect >> network tab.If you getting a 200 response from second connection then there is no way you get 500 error from the same connection

Comment: I am getting 200 on first. but 500 on second.